# column replaced in R

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame,

```
dt2017 <- data.frame(id=LETTERS[1:4],year=2017,city1=c(0,1,0,1),city2=c(0,0,1,0),
                     city3=c(1,0,1,0),city4=c(0,0,0,0))

dt2017
   id year city1 city2 city3 city4
1:  A 2017     0     0     1     0
2:  B 2017     1     0     0     0
3:  C 2017     0     1     1     0
4:  D 2017     1     0     0     0
```

Now, I want the final result like:

```
   id year city1 city2 city3 city4
1:  A 2017     0     0     A     0
2:  B 2017     B     0     0     0
3:  C 2017     0     C     C     0
4:  D 2017     D     0     0     0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you could try using dplyr::mutate_at with an ifelse statement

Comment: @Chris why did you remove u solution.  It works `dt2017 %>% mutate_at(vars(matches('city')), funs(ifelse(.==1, as.character(dt2017$id), 0)))`

Comment: I just wanted to provide the suggestion in a comment, not provide actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We replicate the 'id' column to make the lengths equal with that of 'city' columns and `replace` the location where the 'city' is 0 to '0'

```
dt2017[3:6] <- replace(matrix(dt2017$id[row(dt2017[3:6])], ncol=4), dt2017[3:6]==0, '0')
dt2017
#  id year city1 city2 city3 city4
#1  A 2017     0     0     A     0
#2  B 2017     B     0     0     0
#3  C 2017     0     C     C     0
#4  D 2017     D     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
data[,3:6] <- t(sapply(1:nrow(data),function(i) ifelse(data[i,3:6],data[i,1],0)))
```

Output:

```
  id year city1 city2 city3 city4
1  A 2017     0     0     A     0
2  B 2017     B     0     0     0
3  C 2017     0     C     C     0
4  D 2017     D     0     0     0
```